# Set of elements that don't belong to any power set of these elements [Chartrand P242 10.22 2nd Ed = 10.30 3rd Ed]

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[image]

How and why is the answer $B = A_d$ ? 
I thought : Because $A := \{a, b, c\} \neq \{d, e, f, g, h\}$,
thus $B = \bigcup_{i\in \{d, e, f, g, h\}} A_i$.

---

**Supplementary dated Dec 12 2013:**

By the definition of $B$, we consider $x \in A = \{a, b, c\} $. Thus, are $A_d, A_e, ..., A_h$ really redundant and immaterial to the process of determining $B$? I'm sensing that I should've realised this before doing any work; user rewritten writes that "the rest of the $A_x$ do not enter..." and user Potato analyses only $A_a$, $A_b$, and $A_c$.

Comment: indexes are just ways to name things, probably they could have chosen a different namig scheme but the point is that the set $A_h$ is just some set, and it's unrelated to $h$. $A_h$ is $\{c\}$, and I could call it $TourEiffel$, it is still the same set. $A_h$ is just a name.

Comment: @rewritten: Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure how you are obtaining your answer. I will try to describe how I thought about this. Hopefully it is helpful.

We want the determine $B$. The set $B$ is defined as the set of all elements in $A$ satisfying a certain property: $x$ is not contained in $A_x$. Let us examine each element of $A$ in turn and see if it is in $B$.

Since $A_a$ is null, $a$ is not in $A_a$, so $a$ is in $B$ (because it satisfies the defining property).

Since $A_b=A=\{a,b,c\}$, b is in $A_b$, so it is *not* in $B$ (because it does *not* satisfy the defining property).

Since $A_c=\{a,b\}$, $c$ is not in $A_c$, so $c$ is in $B$.

So $a$ and $c$ work, and we obtain $B=\{a,c\}$.

In contrast, your proposed $B$ is $\{a,b,c\}$  (since the sets you are unioning contain all of these elements).

The fact that the answer ends up being $A_d$ is *entirely coincidental*.

Regarding your edit, you are correct that the rest of the $A_x$ are irrelevant to the process of determining $B$.

Comment: Thank you very much again. +1. It absolutely helps. I've added a supplementary to my OP and I'd be grateful for your answer to it. Would you please answer in your answer if you would?

Answer (score 0):

Being @potato's answer completely correct, I try to clear up the fundamental misunderstanding.

$A$ is the set $\{a,b,c\}$. Let's define a function $g:A\to\mathcal{P}(A)$ such that:

$$
g(a) = A_a = \emptyset \\
g(b) = A_b = A \\
g(c) = A_c = \{a,b\}
$$

The rest of the $A_x$ do not enter at all in this definition.

Now you need to find B, and finally show that B is not in the image of $g$. It's completely irrelevant whether $B$ is $A_d$ or $\omega$ or anything else. The point is that it's different from $g(a)$, $g(b)$ and $g(c)$, so it's not in the image of $g$.